# XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I start XAMPP it shows this

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

when i open localhost/phpmyadmin it shows this error:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

ps : it just was working fine , i just restarted my laptop then this

I tried to to stop any other mysql server but ...

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

service mysql stop
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.

killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
mysql: no process found
mysqld_safe: no process found
mysqld: no process found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue and I solved it this way.

There is a `Your_username.pid` file and `Your_username.err` file in `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/`. Delete them and restart Xampp.

It happens when you turn off your computer unsuccessfully or with an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, removed these files and problem solved.

```
irdev@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ubuntu.pid
irdev@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ubuntu.err
irdev@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ubuntu.log
```

Comment: Blindly removing a PID file is *not* an good idea. Two instances of the same software can wreak havoc in a few cases - there's a reason locking is used. Do a `cat /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ubuntu.pid`, and check that the PID is **not** running before removing. If it's running, use `kill` to stop it.

Comment: @vidarlo Yes. I agree. In my case, I tried most ways to terminate MySQL but problem not solved. Its clear that above solution is not a best solution but it can be the last.